# return a random item in a list of matching strings from a list of strings efficiency

Tags: python, list, random, string-matching

im writing a function to return a random file in a directory, also - i want to be able to match a substring in the file name.

```
def get_rand_file(folder, match=None):
    if match == None:
        return random.choice(os.listdir(folder))
    else:
        matching = []
        for s in os.listdir(folder):
            if match in s:
                matching.append(s)
        return random.choice(matching)
```

this code will work, but i am working with LOTS of files and this code takes a while, i tried doing it with list comprehension and mapping and i couldn't make it work. any suggestions?

Comment: What takes too long? the `os.listdir` call? Or processing entries after that call?

Comment: well, my code runs with many different directories of many files, and rapidly wants to get as many random files and do something else to them... but it just takes too long.. a few moments more each time is still way to long, imagine i run this function like 1000000 times.

Comment: `if match == None:` is better written as `if not match:`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid thanks for that. didnt notice it, that also helps to improve speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def get_rand_file(folder, match=None):
   if match == None:
       return random.choice(os.listdir(folder))
   else:
       return random.choice([s for s in os.listdir(folder) if match in s])
```

Documentation on list comprehensions :

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: thanks, just what i needed. :) the syntax of these excellent features of python are confusing, do you have a link maybe that can explain more about it in general
?